# android 8.0 su not working in terminal on Nexus 5x, ROOTed

Tags: rooting, superuser, supersu

android 8.0 su not working in terminal on Nexus 5x, ROOTed. Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? ROOT-based apps work fine, but in terminal emulators when I try su I just get a stalling of the app.

Comment: Does adb shell su act the same? On a computer

Comment: It works for adb shell surprisingly

Comment: I've tried a few terminal emulators off the play store though, and none are working (that worked before on an older version of android)

Comment: May be Google has made some changes. Does other commands work?

Comment: From the phone's shell, what's the output of `type su`? From a computer, what's the output of `adb shell type su`? Does `/system/bin/sh su` freeze the shell as well?

Comment: Other commands seem to work, the ones I have access to. `type su` returns `/su/bin/su` for both the terminal and `adb shell`. And `/system/bin/sh su` doesn't seem to do anything for both the terminal and `adb shell`, it just goes back to the prompt `bullhead:/ $`